# How do I get an Image from latitude and longitude using Google Places Api in Android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get an image from latitude and longitude information using Google Place API. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you be slightly more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

[Use Geocoder for Reverse Geocoding.](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        // get Place id
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Solution 2: 
Get Place id

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Then you can photos from specific place id.

```
public void getPhotos(String placeId){


    // Specify fields. Requests for photos must always have the PHOTO_METADATAS field.
    List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.PHOTO_METADATAS);

    // Get a Place object (this example uses fetchPlace(), but you can also use findCurrentPlace())
    FetchPlaceRequest placeRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, fields);

    placesClient.fetchPlace(placeRequest).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
        Place place = response.getPlace();

        // Get the photo metadata.
        PhotoMetadata photoMetadata = place.getPhotoMetadatas().get(0);

        // Get the attribution text.
        String attributions = photoMetadata.getAttributions();

        // Create a FetchPhotoRequest.
        FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(photoMetadata)
                .setMaxWidth(500) // Optional.
                .setMaxHeight(300) // Optional.
                .build();
        placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {
            Bitmap bitmap = fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
            if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                // Handle error with given status code.
                Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @John! The place Id "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE" is replaced by the url then?

Comment: No you will get PLACE_ID from above one of the method then you will pass it .

Comment: I'm using this: getPhotos("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=MY KEY"); is this OK? sorry if the question is too basic...just starting on this